Screen Stuck at minimal bash-like editing grub error
Recently I deleted Ubuntu from my system but didn’t delete grub so every time I open my laptop I am stuck at grub error.
How can I land in windows because exit is not working?

Most of the issues related to grub can be solved by boot-repair. See Web-E's answer on How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?).

If you are booting EFI, you can also go into bios and just make windows the default operating system.

In addetion to @user10489 recommenation, reinstall the Windows bootloader.

I presume you want to totally remove Ubuntu and go back to Windows.
You can use the UEFI settings to set Windows as the default bootloader. In case you don't have UEFI (most computers do have UEFI), use OS uninstaller to remove the remnants of the ubuntu installation. It should restore the Windows bootloader https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller.

In case you want to reinstall Ubuntu, go ahead and reinstall from the USB drive, and install it in the partition where the previous version of Ubuntu was installed. Then Ubuntu will fix the bootloader, and will also fix the dual boot with Windows.
